# Iterate over unique pairs in zipped list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists like the below:

```
lst = [['A', 2001, ...], ['A', 2001, ...], ['B', 2001, ...], ['A', 2002, ...], ['C', 2002, ...], ...]
```

I would like to iterate over the combinations of a zipped list between the first two elements of each inner list, excluding duplicates.

I could do the below, but it doesn't exclude duplicates.

```
letters = [item[0] for item in lst]
years = [item[1] for item in lst]

for letter, year in zipped(letters, years):
```

In this example, the pairs that I am looking to iterate over would be:

```
'A': 2001
'B': 2001
'A': 2002
'C': 2002
```

(Note the exclusion of the additional `'A':2001` pair)

I feel that my attempted code is more complicated than it needs to be. ANy ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: Store pai in a list then set() to remove duplicates

Comment: What is `zipped`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `set` to remove the duplicates:

```py
for letter, year in set(zipped(letters, years)):
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` and ignore the subiterator.

```
from itertools import groupby


def f(x):
    return x[:2]


for (letter, number), _ in groupby(sorted(lst, key=f), f):
    print(letter, number)
```